# How to seek file pointer line by line in python

Tags: python

I am trying to seek the file pointer line by line, i found the following code

```
fo = open("temp.tmp", "r")
print "Name of the file: ", fo.name
"""Assuming file has following 5 lines:

     This is 1st line
     This is 2nd line
     This is 3rd line
     This is 4th line
     This is 5th line
"""
line = fo.readline()
print "Read Line: %s" % (line)
# Again set the pointer to the beginning
fo.seek(3, 0)
line = fo.readline()
print "Read Line: %s" % (line)
fo.close()
```

but, it moves file pointer character by character, is there any way to seek the pointer line by line

Comment: Why not just `with open(...) as fo: for line in fo: ...`?

Comment: `readline()` uses a read-ahead buffer to find where the next newline character is to be found. `seek()` reflects where that buffer has read up to.

Comment: Why do you need to seek in the first place? If you need to refer to earlier lines, just store those lines in a variable. Don't read them from the file again.

Comment: i solved the issue logically, but just eager to know is there any way to seek line by line

Comment: @jonrsharpe with open(...) as fo: for line in fo: its one of the way, but we can do as I done

Comment: ...what? What are you actually trying to *achieve*?